# MySqlDataReader close connection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, iis

This is my code for select data from table in MySql:

```
            MySqlDataReader msdr;

            MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            string commandLine = "SELECT id,token FROM Table WHERE id = @id AND token = @token;";

            cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@token", token);

            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //do stuff.....

            msdr.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
```

As you can see i close this two:

```
        msdr.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
```

And i want to ask if i need to close this two? or it will be ok to close only the `cmd.Connection.Close();`

The reason i asked it it because sometimes i get this error when i try to select data in table: 
`Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Too many connections`

And i want to know if it's because i don't close this connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best coding for this is the following

```
using(MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    string commandLine = "SELECT id,token FROM Table WHERE id = @id AND token = @token;";
    cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@token", token);

    cmd.Connection = connect;
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    using(msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

         //do stuff.....
    } // <- here the DataReader is closed and disposed.

}  // <- here at the closing brace the connection is closed and disposed as well the command
```

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will keep your connection closed and disposed as well as the command object. There is no need to call explicitily Close on MySqlConnection or MySqlDataReader because the using statement will do this for you ALSO in case of Exceptions triggered in your code between the open and close of the connection

In your original code it is enough to close the connection just one time with the command, datareader or the connection itself, because they work with the same object instance, but if you have an exception then your code fails to close the connection and thus you risk the 'too many connections open' problem

**UPDATE for C# 8.0**
In this version of the language there is a small but useful enhancement to the using statement. It is called [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations)

With this change the code above could be written removing the braces around the using blocks

```
using MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
using MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
string commandLine = "SELECT id,token FROM Table WHERE id = @id AND token = @token;";

.....
cmd.Connection.Open();
using msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//do stuff.....
```

When the method exits all the using declaration will act to dispose their repective declared variable

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this code in a method, it's better to close the data reader as well as the data connection